# Simplest ever apply_gradients throws 'op' attribute error

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I am learning to use tensorflow library. Every time I try to use simplest (I guess) possible example of gradient-based learning I get the same error, which makes me stuck.

Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='X')
a = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name= 'A')
y = tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.float32, name='Y')

ey = tf.multiply(x, a)
los = (y - ey)**2

optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.2)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for counter in range(100):
    grd = sess.run(optim.compute_gradients(loss=los))
    sess.run(optim.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grd))
```

On the last line, I get following error:
*AttributeError: 'numpy.float32' object has no attribute 'op'.*

Thank you in advance for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input of `apply_gradients` must be a tensor not a numpy array. Because, it is not meant to be called at each step of the learning but just once when building your graph. In fact, it "creates" the "training step" in which variables are updated using the computed gradient

You should use that kind of code instead:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='X')
a = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name= 'A')
y = tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.float32, name='Y')

ey = tf.multiply(x, a)
los = (y - ey)**2

optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.2)
grads, vars = zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(loss))
train_step = optim.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grads)

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
for counter in range(100):
    grd = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict = {...})
```

Comment: Ha... Got it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The tensorflow converts tensor into numpy array when stored and evaluated using sess.run(). The apply_gradients method of GradientDescentOptimizer raises TypeError since it requires tensor as input as described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/GradientDescentOptimizer). This causing problem in the original code.

`for counter in range(100):
    grd = sess.run(optim.compute_gradients(loss=los))
    sess.run(optim.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grd))`

The solution to this problem is to define all the operations before starting session.
There may be cases where gradients need to be post-processed before updating weights. All such post-processing logic need to be defined  before session begins.

Here is a simple example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant(1, dtype=tf.float32, name='X')
a = tf.Variable(1, dtype=tf.float32, name= 'A')
y = tf.constant(10, dtype=tf.float32, name='Y')

ey = tf.multiply(x, a)
loss = (y - ey)**2

optim = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.2)
grads = optim.compute_gradients(loss)
train_step = optim.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=grads)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for counter in range(100):
        sess.run(train_step)
```